# Nuke is not installing the latest version available on the GitHub

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I just added a new pod my podfile - pod 'Nuke' to my iOS app

pofile.lock shows that app installed version is 4.1.2

However, on GitHub, Nuke version 5.1 is available. Podspec shows version 5.1

https://github.com/kean/Nuke

What may be the issue?

Comment: can you share the podfile?

Comment: found the issue. please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I upgrade cocoa pods to 1.2.0, I was able to install nuke 5.1 version